# Including AWS credentials with JAR file

Tags: java, eclipse, amazon-web-services, jar

I created a JAR executable of a program which uses AWS to communicate with a DynamoDB database. I remember setting up my credentials through Eclipse so that I would have access to the database, but this doesn't seem to have carried over to the JAR file since these credentials are saved on my computer and do not get packaged with the JAR. I've noticed that the JAR actually has access to the database on the computer I used to create it, but on any other computer, any tasks that require the program to access the database give the error message "Error scanning table: Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain."

How should I include the credentials with the app in order to ensure that anyone running the JAR will have access to the database?

EDIT: In case it makes a difference, I think the way I originally set the credentials was in Eclipse via AWS > Preferences > Profile Configuration.

Comment: Are all users that would have the jar trusted?

Comment: Yes, all of them are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on what you've posted I see a few options:

1. Create an AWS user that is of the "Programatic Access" type for each user who is going to run your Jar.  The user will need to then create ~/.aws/credentials with the credentials you give them.  This is a semi manual step but it allows you to turn off a particular user.
2. Assuming you have a shell file to start up your Jar file, create the environment variables `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` and export them to be run by your users.
3. If this is truly a raw Jar, then in your main() (or some other method that you know gets called before anything in AWS is called) do a `System.setProperty("aws.accessKeyId", "youraccesskey")` and `System.setProperty("aws.secretKey", "yoursecretkey")` to set these as system properties.

The last two suggestions are pretty dangerous.  You may trust you users today but what happens when one of them is no longer trusted?  The first option allows you to disable a single user.

Answer (score 2):

I don't recommend hardcoding credentials in the JAR, but if you really want to it, there a few ways.

When you create the client you can use `.withCredentials()` to pass in your key and secret. For example:

```
BasicAWSCredentials awsCreds = new BasicAWSCredentials("access_key_id", "secret_key");
AmazonDynamoDBClient dbClient = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard()
                        .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCreds))
                        .build();
```

If you want to make it global and have every client use it automatically, you can set these Java properties before you use any AWS code:

```
System.setProperty("aws.accessKeyId", "access_key_id");
System.setProperty("aws.secretKey", "secret_key");
```

For more information, see:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/credentials.html

Answer (score 1):

You can create an 'AWSCredentials' object programmatically like this:

```
AWSCredentials credentials = new AWSCredentials() {
  public String getAWSSecretKey() { return "your secret key here"; }
  public String getAWSAccessKeyId() { return "your access id here"; }
};
AmazonSimpleDB simpleDb = new AmazonSimpleDBClient(credentials); 
AmazonS3Client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials); 
//and so on...
```